# Automorphisms of a finite partition lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, set-partition

Is the group of automorphisms of a lattice of partitions of the set $X$, where $|X| = n$, isomorphic to $S_n$? I think it is (for sure it's not 'smaller' than $S_n$), but i can't find any proof of it in papers or books. I did try to prove it myself but it's not that easy, can't think of a counterexample either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is the group of automorphisms of a lattice of partitions of the set $X$,
where $|X|=n$, isomorphic to $S_n$?**

Yes, if $n\neq 2$.

Assume that $X = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
Let $\Pi(X)$ be the lattice of partitions of $X$.
For each $i\in X$,
let $\widehat{i}$ ($i$ hat) be the partition $\{\{i\}, X\setminus\{i\}\}$
of $X$ that has two cells
where one is the singleton $\{i\}$ and the other is the complement
$X\setminus \{i\}$.
Let $\widehat{X} = \{\widehat{1},\widehat{2},\ldots,\widehat{n}\}$,
which is a subset of $\Pi(X)$.
I will indicate why $\widehat{X}$ is an $\textrm{Aut}(\Pi(X))$-orbit
and why the restriction map $\rho\colon \alpha\mapsto \alpha|_{\widehat{X}}$
is an isomorphism of $\textrm{Aut}(\Pi(X))$
onto $\textrm{Sym}(\widehat{X})$.

1. Every automorphism of $\Pi(X)$ permutes the elements of $\widehat{X}$.
   (This says that $\widehat{X}$ is a union of $\textrm{Aut}(\Pi(X))$-orbits,
   which 
   is enough to guarantee that the restriction map $\rho$ is a homomorphism from
   $\textrm{Aut}(\Pi(X))$ to $\textrm{Sym}(\widehat{X})$.)
2. Distinct automorphisms of $\Pi(X)$ have distinct restrictions to $\widehat{X}$.
   ($\rho$ is injective.)
3. Every permutation of $\widehat{X}$ is the restriction of some
   automorphism of $\Pi(X)$.
   ($\rho$ is surjective.)

The reason the first claim is true when $n>2$ is that
$\widehat{X}$ is definable as the set of partitions of $X$
that are coatoms of $\Pi(X)$ that have exactly
$|X|-1$ complementary atoms.
(Then we use the fact that lattice automorphisms must map
'coatoms with $|X|-1$ complementary atoms'
to other
'coatoms with $|X|-1$ complementary atoms'.)
To see that $\widehat{X}$ is exactly
the set of partitions of $X$
that are coatoms that have exactly
$|X|-1$ complementary atoms, note that
the coatoms of $\Pi(X)$ are the partitions
of $X$ with $2$ cells,
say $\{I,J\}$, while the atoms of $\Pi(X)$ are the partitions
that have exactly one nonsingleton cell and
that nonsingleton cell has $2$ elements.
The number of atoms that are complementary
to the coatom $\{I,J\}$ is $|I|\cdot |J|$,
since the nonsingleton cell of a complementary atom
will have the form $\{i,j\}$ where $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.
Now, if $|I|+|J|=|X|$ and $|I|\cdot |J|=|X|-1$,
then $|I|$ and $J$ are the roots of the polynomial
$f(t)=t^2-|X|\cdot t + (|X|-1)$, hence $|I|$
and $|J|$ are the numbers
$1$ and $|X|-1$ in some order. This is enough to show that
a coatom of $\Pi(X)$ has exactly $|X|-1$ complementary
atoms iff the coatom is a member of $\widehat{X}$.

The reason the second claim is true when $n>2$ is that
$\widehat{X}$ is a lattice-theoretic
generating set for $\Pi(X)$.
(Every atom in $\Pi(X)$ is a meet of elements
of $\widehat{X}$, and every element of
$\Pi(X)$ is a join of atoms. Thus
$\bigvee \bigwedge \widehat{X} = \Pi(X)$.)
Since two lattice automorphisms that agree on a
lattice-theoretic generating set are equal,
distinct automorphisms of $\Pi(X)$ will have distinct
restrictions to $\widehat{X}$

The reason the third claim is true when $n>2$ is that
any permutation $\pi$ of the set $X$
induces an automorphism $\bar{\pi}$
on $\Pi(X)$
whose action on $\widehat{X}$ mirrors
the action of $\pi$ on $X$: $\bar{\pi}(\widehat{i})=\widehat{\pi(i)}$.
For example, if $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\pi=(1\;2)(3\;4)\in \textrm{Sym}(X)$,
then $\bar{\pi}$ is the automorphism of $\Pi(X)$
that maps a partition $\{I,J,K\}$ to $\{\pi(I),\pi(J),\pi(K)\}$
and in particular it maps $\widehat{i} = \{\{i\},X\setminus \{i\}\}$ to
$\{\{\pi(i)\},X\setminus \{\pi(i)\}\}$. Thus $\bar{\pi}|_{\widehat{X}}=(\widehat{1}\;\widehat{2})(\widehat{3}\;\widehat{4})$.